# R remove element from list

Tags: r, list, element

How do I remove an element from a list in R?
Imagine this workflow:

```
# create list
my_list <- lapply(1:10, function(x) x)
# find which ones to exclude
my_list_boolean <- sapply(my_list, function(x) ifelse(x%%2>0,F,T))
# does not work like this!
my_list[[my_list_boolean]]
```

Is there a solution not having to use a for loop and create a big logic around my statement?

Comment: `ifelse(x%%2>0,F,T)` can be **greatly** simplified to `x%%2<=0`. No `ifelse` at all. Try `identical(ifelse(x%%2>0,F,T), x%%2 <= 0)` if you doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `[]` and not `[[]]`

```r
my_list <- lapply(1:10, function(x) x)
# find which ones to exclude
my_list_boolean <- sapply(my_list, function(x) ifelse(x%%2>0,F,T))
# does not work like this!
my_list[my_list_boolean]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 10
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

You can thus select element of the list with logical vector and not the content (which is `[[]]`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
my_list[my_list_boolean]
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 4
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 6
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 8
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 10
```